# ActiveRecord: Order by ID or column value first and the rest of the query functions the same

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, psql

I am trying to write an ActiveRecord query to where I need certain values for columns to come before the rest of the query. For example:

If I have 6 records in a table but I want 2 records with different IDs to come before the rest of the query

Here is a record set:

```
[{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5},{id: 6}]
```

And I would like to output:

```
[{id: 3},{id: 5},{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 4},{id: 6}]
```

Notice the 3 and the 5 are at the beginning.

How would I go about writing this in active record?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What criteria are you using to decide that 3 and 5 should be at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which criteria your are using to sort the items with id 3 and 5 in the example, but assuming your are prepending an equally sorted group at the beginning, you can do something like this:

```rb
# let's say 'items' are the ActiveRecord items that you want to order
prepended_ids = [3,5]
items.order("CASE WHEN (id IN (#{prepended_ids.join(',')})) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, id")
```

note that this will not work if `prepended_ids` is blank, so the complete solution would be:

```rb
prepended_ids = [3,5]
items.order("#{"CASE WHEN (id IN (#{prepended_ids.join(',')})) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC" if prepended_ids.present?}, id")
```